# Add click event and delay event to div (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the page to slide up a div (#splash) when it loads **OR** at any point, the mouse can be clicked to load the slide up. Heres my code which isn't working

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
         openEffect : 'none',
         closeEffect    : 'none'
    });

    $("#splash").click(function(){
        $("#splash").slideUp(3000,"swing");
    });

    $("#splash").delay(2000).slideUp(3000,"swing");

});
```

I want it to slide up sorry. The splash is initially the size of the entire page. I want it to slide up on load after delay, or when I click it.

Currently the div only slides up after the 2000 delay, and not when it is clicked

Comment: Do you want it to slide down or up?

Comment: You need to bind mouse click to the window, not to #splash - otherwise it only slides in when #splash itself is clicked.

Comment: Up? down? I am dizzy figuring out what you are talking about.

Comment: @ SSM agreed. just to clarify, the div is invisible on page load?

Comment: `$(window).bind( "click", function(){ $("#splash").slideUp( 3000, "swing" ); });`

Comment: I want it to slide up sorry. The splash is initially the size of the entire page. I want it to slide up on load after delay, or when I click it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delay function prevents the slideUp in click to execute. Use setTimeout instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#splash").click(function(){
        $("#splash").slideUp(3000,"swing");
    });

    //Bad code: 
    //$("#splash").delay(5000).slideUp(3000,"swing");

    //Use setTimeOut 
    setTimeout(function (){$("#splash").slideUp(3000,"swing");} ,5000);

});
```

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/QXEVP/

Comment: why doesn't the click method bind to an even and execute respective of the code that is running?

Comment: The click function binds okay. $("#splash").slideUp does not execute till $("#splash").delay elsewhere is cleared

Comment: this is the only way that seems to work. didnt realise there were two functions for delay

Comment: jQuery's `delay` method adds a delay between animations in the queue. `setTimeout` executes a callback  after a set amount of time.